# ajax on click update form content

Tags: php, ajax

This is my form.

[image]

If i click the status content like `progress` or `dsgs` a textfield should appear. If i type text in it and click outside or press enter the old content should updated with the new one. I need it to be done with ajax and php. I am a beginner in php and ajax. Any reference or how can i do this?

This is my code for add status

```
$insert_task = "INSERT INTO `tbl_task` (`intProjectid`,`intUserid`,`dtDate`,`dtFinishdate`,`varIssue`,`varStatus`,`varNeedhelp` )VALUES ('".$id."','".$userid."','".$dtdate."','".$dtfinish."','".$issue."','".$status."','".$help."');";
$insert_query=mysql_query($insert_task);
```

Comment: I just used the javascript show hide function to hide the text and display the box

Comment: So, you didn't implemented anything yet ? Post whatever you got.

Comment: I just planned to use javascript show hide to hide the text and display the box. I need ajax for update the content. I am a beginner and have no idea about ajax. I need some initial help so i didn't implement it yet.

Comment: Can you post your form's html code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't give me anything but I've tried to implement something by guessing and hope if it doesn't solve your problem but at least it will help you. Following code is for your ajax functionality, you can put it inside the head tag of your page between script tags-

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var eventFlag=false;
            var originalText='';
            $('#mytable tr td span').click(function(e){
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                $(this).siblings().show().focus();
                $(this).hide();
                eventFlag=false;
                originalText=$(this).siblings().val();
            });

            $('#mytable tr td input').blur(function(e){
                if(!eventFlag && validate($(this))) doAjax($(this));
                else
                {
                    $(this).siblings().show();
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });

            $('#mytable tr td input').keypress(function(e){
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if(code==13)
                {
                    if(validate($(this)))
                    {
                        doAjax($(this));
                        eventFlag=true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(this).siblings().show();
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                }
            });

            function validate(input)
            {
                console.log(input.val()+" "+originalText);
                if(input.val()!='' && input.val()!=originalText)
                return true
                else return false;
            }

            function doAjax(input)
            {
                var formData="proId="+input.attr('id')+"&text="+input.val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "update.php",
                        data: formData,
                        success: function(data){
                            if(data==1) 
                            {
                                input.siblings().text(input.val()).show();
                                input.hide();
                            }   
                            else
                            {
                                input.siblings().show();
                                input.hide();
                                alert("something Wrong !");
                            }   
                        },
                        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                            alert("Error:"+xhr.status+" "+thrownError);
                        }
                    });
            }

        });
```

And I guessed your form could be something like this

```
<form action="#" method="post">
        <table id="mytable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Issue</th><th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Login</td><td id="1"><span>Progress</span><input id="1" type="text" value="Progress" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Something Else</td><td id="2"><span>Anything</span><input id="2" type="text" value="Anything"/></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>    
        </table>
    </form>
```

Put this inside your head or stylesheet (without style tag)

```
<style>
        #mytable tr td input{display:none;}
</style>
```

And your update.php file should be something like

```
<?php

$proId = $_POST['proId'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
$update_task="update tbl_task set varStatus='".$text."' where intProjectid=".$proId;
if(mysql_query($update_task))
{
    echo "1";
}
else 
{
    echo "0";
}   

?>
```

I've tested it and working. The id I've used in the form is by assuming that you have id's for each of your status and you should update instead of inserting to change the status. let me know if it helps or if you need more help, I'll be on touch. Thanks!

Comment: I have encountered another problem with this. Is it possible to use select menu instead of text field. For that what should i do?

Comment: Is your site live niw, can I see it ?

Comment: Sorry. My site is not in live. I have fixed the problem asked above using your code. But If i updated the status to completed then the select menu should not appears on click. But my new problem is if i updated the status to completed and then click the same status the select menu appears. But if i modified and refresh the page it works fine. I need it to be correct with out refresh the page. How can i do that? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.